# gradle - project as a dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java project structure as follows:

```
- root-directory (has no .gradle file)
    - project_1
        - build.gradle
        - settings.gradle
    - project_2
        - build.gradle
        - settings.gradle
    - project_3
        - build.gradle
        - settings.gradle
```

`project_2` depends on `project_1`, and this dependency is defined as follows:

```
- project_2/build.gradle
  implementation(project(":project_1"))
- project_2/settings.gradle
  include(":project_1")
  project(":project_1").projectDir = new File("../project_1")
```

And, `project_3` depends on `project_2`, and this dependency is defined as follows:

```
- project_3/build.gradle
  implementation(project(":project_2"))
- project_3/settings.gradle
  include(":project_2")
  project(":project_2").projectDir = new File("../project_2")
```

Now, when I build `project_3` by running `>> ./gradlew build` teminal command in `./project_3/` directory, the following error occurs:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':project_2'.
> Project with path ':project_1' could not be found in project ':project_2'.
```

I want to be able to build each project from it's own directory. How do I resolve this issue?

**Update:** I tried converting the `root-directory` into project root by adding the following:

```
- root-directory/settings.gradle
  rootProject.name = "root"
  include(":project_1", ":project_2", ":project_3")
- root-directory/build.gradle
  // Nothing in this file
```

And removed, `project(":project_#").projectDir = new File("../project_#")` line from all the sub-projects' `settings.gradle` file. But even after this, the build command from each individual projects' directory didn't work.

Comment: There must be a single root project, and thus a single settings.gradle file, and all commands must be executed from the root directory. For example= `./gradlew build` to build all projects, or `./gradlew :project_1:build` to only build project_1. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Quick correction: commands do not have to be executed from the root project. You should be able to run `gradle build` from any of the project directories. You just have to adjust the path to the wrapper script if you're using it.

Answer (score 4):

do not define `include(":project_1/2/3")` in the module-level `build gradle`, instead use the root project's `settings.gradle` to define this ...

```
include ":project_1", ":project_2", ":project_3"
rootProject.name = "SomeApp"
```

and then you can reference these sub-projects in a module-level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
     api project(':project_1')
     implementation project(':project_2')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Project dependencies require a project path, not just a project name:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":project_1")
}
```

Note the `:` before the project name: it turns the project name into a project path relative to the root project.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that's how I wrote the build script (it's the syntax). But I missed it while writing the question. And I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had subprojects which were not java projects. i had to do

```
allprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

in build.gradle